# How to create process attachment in the Activiti

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I have used the following code in the Alfresco 4.1 but after upgrading to Alfresco 4.2 it stop working and throw exception like "org.activiti.engine.ActivitiObjectNotFoundException: Process instance activiti$401 doesn't exist". I've checked the process id in database it is exist. Any ideas how to create attachments?

the failing code below

```
// 1. find task by params 
WorkflowTask task = workflowService.findTask(roomId, assignee, PrintOrderModel.BASKET_TASK); 

// 2. create attachment

Attachment attachment = taskService.createAttachment("url", null, instaceId, name, "", url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activiti does not use the "activiti$" prefix, it's just used by Alfresco APIs. When using the TaskService createAttachment please use 
Attachment attachment = taskService.createAttachment("url", null, "401", name, "", url); 
and not activiti$401